# Как вывести записи WP сортируя по массиву с их ID, WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

есть 22 постов, которые выводится стандартным циклом WP. Так же есть простой масссив, в котором хранятся ID всех постов, но в другом порядке.
Вопрос: Как вывести посты в порядке в котором их ID лежат в массиве?

P.S Сначала подумал пройтись циклом по этому массиву и через id получить пост, но сомневаюсь что такой подход правильный

Comment: Я бы такое сделал через произвольное поле поста, записав в него значение порядка из [непонятного] массива.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то нужно отсортировать уже готовый массив постов по значению ID. Для этого можно использовать функцию usort():

```
$posts = get_posts();

function sortByID($a, $b){
    return $a->ID - $b->ID;
}

usort($posts, "sortByID");
```

PS: Можно написать и альтернативные решения, например через asort() или array_multisort().